# urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given> python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urlopen

I have this code in python 3.4

```
import urllib.request


def read_text():
    document = open(r"C:\mystuff\udacity\pruebatxt.txt")
    lec = document.read()
    document.close()
    print(lec)
    check_profanity(lec)

def check_profanity (text_to_check):
    print(text_to_check)
```

### finally, i found the sollution by changing  follow line

```
    lecture = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q="+ urllib.parse.quote(text_to_check))
    output=lecture .read()
    print(output)

    lecture.close()
read_text()
```

And it gives me this error:

```
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1159, in do_request_
    raise URLError('no host given')
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`urlopen()` returns a *response*, not a request. You cannot pass that to `urlopen()` *again*.

Remove the redundant `urlopen()` call:

```
lecture = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q="+text_to_check)
output = lecture.read()
```

You may have a broken proxy configuration; verify that your proxies are sane by inspecting what Python finds in the Windows registry with:

```
print(urllib.request.getproxies())
```

or bypass proxy support altogether with:

```
lecture = urllib.request.urlopen(
    "http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q="+text_to_check
    proxies={})
```

Comment: What does `print(urllib.request.getproxies())` show? Does it work when you add `proxies={}` to the `urlopen()` call?

Comment: Thanks for your help, in the code i change a line and i found the solution

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns a binary string. It would be better to decode it into ascii format:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q=" + urllib.parse.quote(text_to_check)) as response:
    output = response.read()
output = output.decode('ascii')
print (output)
```